# Python: how to select rows with single word in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, text, split

i have a dataframe like this:

```
id    text
1     one two three 
2     one two 
3     four
4     six seven
5     84
6     4x2
```

I wonder if integers like **84 (fifth row)** would be a problem ?

the output should be like this (single word rows only):

```
id  text
3   four
5   84
6   4x2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

create a boolean mask via `strip()`,`split()` and `eq()` method:

```
mask=df['text'].str.strip().str.split(' ').str.len().eq(1)
```

Finally pass that mask:

```
out=df[mask]
#OR
out=df.loc[mask]
```

now if you print `out` you will get your desired output

### update:

For selecting 2,3 and4 words just make a slight change in mask:

```
mask=df['text'].str.strip().str.split(' ').str.len()
```

Finally:

```
df[(mask>1) & (mask<5)]
#OR
df.loc[(mask>1) & (mask<5)]
```

Comment: I'm sorry to Bother You Again. What can I do to select rows consisting of 2,3 or 4 words.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like that:

```
column_ok = []  # Column you want to keep
for column in df:
    if column.find(" ")<=0: # If there is not a space in the column name
        column_ok.append(column)       
df_new = df[column_ok].copy()  # Will copy the data frame with the "good columns"
```

You have to find if there is a space in your column name. The integer will be kept with this method.